# variáveis globais php

Tags: php, session

Olá, eu creio que isso seja simples, eu estou trabalhando em um projeto no qual preciso iniciar 3 strings em 80% das páginas do sistema, em php, então qual seria o melhor método para o usuário apenas mudar o texto em um documento, e eu poder realizar a inclusão em todas as páginas???

explicando melhor, vou criar um arquivo configura.php, onde o cliente vai abrir usando um compilador ou editor de texto e setar o valor das 3 strings, separadamente.

ps: eu já fui aconselhado a usar session, porém minha dúvida é como eu posso carregar 3 strings separadas usando a session.

Comment: Você já não vai incluir o arquivo `configura.php` em todos os arquivos? Se sim, não precisa fazer mais nada. Não vejo porquê utilizar sessões se o valor destas variáveis forem constantes.

Comment: Anderson, posso incluir o arquivo sim, você poderia me da um exemplo da sintaxe para atribuir os valores vindos de configura.php a variaveis de qualquer página?

Comment: Define as variáveis em `configura.php` mesmo e em todo arquivo que você incluí-lo elas existirão.

Comment: Andreson, algo tipo ao incluir pode haver conflito com as variáveis de mesmo nome certo?
Mas obrigado a dica, vou testar pra ver se funciona 100% aqui!

Comment: coloca o comentário em Responder a Pergunta para eu poder lhe dar os pontos de reputação.

Comment: Motivo do voto de fechamento é que não há como dizer qual é o melhor modo de resolver. Pelo o que descreveu parece não ser necessário o uso de variáveis de sessão. A primeira coisa que imaginei é uso de constante, mas aí você fala que o usuário vai editar um config.php, e isso muda toda a lógica. Como é o formato desse config.php e como ele é acessado? Se puder mostrar como é esse arquivo, acho que pode tornar a pergunta mais objetiva. Do contrário, receberá respostas dipersas, palpitando o que poderia fazer. Mas usar session, eu acho pouco provável.

Answer (score 4):

Criar [SESSIONS](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) é bem simples, só fazer:

```
session_start(); //Inicia a sessão
//Seta as variáveis
$_SESSION['string1'] = 'Oi';
$_SESSION['string2'] = 'Olá';
$_SESSION['string3'] = 'Eu sou uma string';
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel se esses valores forem constantes do sistema crie um arquivo e dentro dele defina constantes desse jeito:

define(NOME_CONSTANTE1,'valor');

define(NOME_CONSTANTE2,'valor');

em seguida faça um include nas páginas que vai utilizar.

É isso mesmo em letra maiúscula em seguida utilize NOME_CONSTANTE1 ou NOME_CONSTANTE2 no seu script aonde quiser!  Se o valor dessas variaveis não forem constantes use session!

[image: Constantes de sistema]

Comment: já agora, como faço depois para poder mostrar as constantes? obg

Comment: Eu não entendi o que quis dizer com mostrar, mas se está se referindo a imprimi-las use : echo NOME_CONSTANTE1;

Comment: era mesmo isso. pensei que fosse necessário algo mais que isso. obrigado.

Comment: Disponha meu Rei!